# Is it possible to copy control array to another control array in VB6?

Tags: vb6, control-array

I want to copy content of control array  to another control array, is it possible in VB6?
please help

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The array is a list of object references with some extra plumbing so there is little point in copying, you would end up with a list of the same references. Did you mean clone?

Comment: I have a control array of labels, and need to take a duplicate copy of it to perform deletion of elements from the original array and update it after deletion.

Comment: why cannot you just do it? Go through the control array and make copies by setting properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a second control array to hold the values in the labels of the first one, you just need a normal array.  Suppose you have a control array of three labels called myLabel:

```
Dim LabelValues(2) as String
Dim i as Integer

Sub DeleteAndSaveLabelValues
    For i = 0 to 2
        With myLabel
            LabelValues(i) = .Caption(i)
            .Caption(i) = ""
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

To replace the label values, just iterate through the control array again and set the Caption to the appropriate array value.